# cron job - 2 different jobs scheduling

Tags: cron

```
*/5 * * * * /dev/file1/test/test1/fls/mdm/test1.sh
*/7 * * * * /dev/file1/test/test1/fls/mdm/test2.sh
```

I have 2 cron jobs - job1 and job2. I need to schedule the second job to run few minutes later than ongoing cron job.

Can anyone guide me how to achieve this?

I entered this after typing crontab -e ->

```
00 05 * * * * /dev/file1/test/test1/fls/mdm/test1.sh 02 05 * * * * /dev/file1/test/test1/fls/mdm/test2.sh
```

When I try the below one, it is working.

```
00 */5 * * * /dev/file1/test/test1/fls/mdm/test1.sh 
02 */5 * * * /dev/file1/test/test1/fls/mdm/test2.sh
```

I'm not sure if I use the second script it will be triggered in different times.

Error Message: errors in crontab file can't install

Comment: From the cron tag: Questions about configuring cron for systems or administration are OFF TOPIC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

00 05 * * * * /dev/file1/test/test1/fls/mdm/test1.sh
02 05 * * * * /dev/file1/test/test1/fls/mdm/test2.sh

I guess this should do the job as the first will run at 05 00 am and the second will run at 05 02 am.

Comment: I'm getting error. It says error in crontab file. can't install

Comment: Oh are you putting the blank line between these two task ?
if yes don't do that.

It should be like :


00 05 * * * * /dev/file1/test/test1/fls/mdm/test1.sh
02 05 * * * * /dev/file1/test/test1/fls/mdm/test2.sh

Comment: Yes, I was using blank line. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. Not sure if I'm doing any mistake. Will the above script run for every 5 mins?

Comment: can you share the screenshot of the info that you are saving there so that I can make sure that if you are doing it right or not,

also do provide the full error.

Comment: Also the job will not run in every 5 minutes it will run only once at 05:02 AM. Please let me know the actual need here. So that I can provide you the exact answer. Like if you need these jobs running multiple times.

Comment: I guess that you need to run these task every five minutes and the second job needs to run after 2 minutes of the first job you should try these two enries.

`0-59/5 * * * * /dev/file1/test/test1/fls/mdm/test1.sh`
`2-59/5 * * * * /dev/file1/test/test1/fls/mdm/test2.sh`